# My machine has enough RAM+SWAP memory but spit out `Out Of Memory` error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda, out-of-memory

I am trying to run a deep learning program on a nVidia board (Jetson TX2).
This machine has about 8 GB RAM and 128 GB SWAP partition.

Ubuntu 18.04 is running on my machine.

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$ uname -a
Linux nvidia 4.9.201-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 15 14:54:23 PST 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

About 8+128GB memory is available on my machine.

```bash
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        1.7G        5.7G        3.6M        266M        6.7G
Swap:          125G        384M        125G
```

And, virtual memory setting is not limited.

```bash
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 28396
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 28396
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

However, when I run a deep learning program, it produced OOM error and dead.

```bash
$ ./build/testbed --mode nerf --scene data/nerf/fox/
15:28:56 INFO     Loading NeRF dataset from
15:28:56 INFO       data/nerf/fox/transforms.json
15:28:57 SUCCESS  Loaded 50 images after 0s
15:28:57 INFO       cam_aabb=[min=[1.0229,-1.33309,-0.378748], max=[2.46175,1.00721,1.41295]]
15:28:59 INFO     Loading network config from: configs/nerf/base.json
15:28:59 INFO     GridEncoding:  Nmin=16 b=1.51572 F=2 T=2^19 L=16
Warning: FullyFusedMLP is not supported for the selected architecture 62. Falling back to CutlassMLP. For maximum performance, raise the target GPU architecture to 75+.
Warning: FullyFusedMLP is not supported for the selected architecture 62. Falling back to CutlassMLP. For maximum performance, raise the target GPU architecture to 75+.
Warning: FullyFusedMLP is not supported for the selected architecture 62. Falling back to CutlassMLP. For maximum performance, raise the target GPU architecture to 75+.
15:28:59 INFO     Density model: 3--[HashGrid]-->32--[FullyFusedMLP(neurons=64,layers=3)]-->1
15:28:59 INFO     Color model:   3--[Composite]-->16+16--[FullyFusedMLP(neurons=64,layers=4)]-->3
15:28:59 INFO       total_encoding_params=13074912 total_network_params=9728
GPUMemoryArena: Warning: GPU 0 does not support virtual memory. Falling back to regular allocations, which will be larger and can cause occasional stutter.
Killed
```

Here is system log message

```
[20539.993902] testbed invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24082c2(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_HIGHMEM|__GFP_NOWARN|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[20540.007325] testbed cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[20540.007336] CPU: 0 PID: 10005 Comm: testbed Not tainted 4.9.201-tegra #1
[20540.007338] Hardware name: quill (DT)
[20540.007340] Call trace:
[20540.007348] [<ffffff800808b9f8>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x198
[20540.007352] [<ffffff800808bfbc>] show_stack+0x24/0x30
[20540.007356] [<ffffff800845abe8>] dump_stack+0xa0/0xc8
[20540.007361] [<ffffff8008257c54>] dump_header+0x6c/0x1b8
[20540.007366] [<ffffff80081c843c>] oom_kill_process+0x29c/0x4c8
[20540.007369] [<ffffff80081c8b14>] out_of_memory+0x1e4/0x308
[20540.007372] [<ffffff80081ce608>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x810/0xcb8
[20540.007376] [<ffffff800857d884>] nvmap_alloc_pages_exact+0x54/0xe8
[20540.007378] [<ffffff800857ecd8>] nvmap_alloc_handle+0xad0/0xfd0
[20540.007382] [<ffffff800858b104>] nvmap_ioctl_alloc+0xdc/0x118
[20540.007384] [<ffffff80085854d4>] nvmap_ioctl+0xc4/0x5f0
[20540.007387] [<ffffff8008271f58>] do_vfs_ioctl+0xb0/0x8d8
[20540.007389] [<ffffff800827280c>] SyS_ioctl+0x8c/0xa8
[20540.007392] [<ffffff8008083900>] el0_svc_naked+0x34/0x38
[20540.007418] Mem-Info:
[20540.007426] active_anon:669 inactive_anon:671 isolated_anon:0
                active_file:458 inactive_file:353 isolated_file:0
                unevictable:3880 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
                slab_reclaimable:10453 slab_unreclaimable:18311
                mapped:304 shmem:1 pagetables:2384 bounce:0
                free:165587 free_pcp:211 free_cma:150521
[20540.007431] Node 0 active_anon:2676kB inactive_anon:2684kB active_file:1832kB inactive_file:1412kB unevictable:15520kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:1216kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:4kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB pages_scanned:524 all_unreclaimable? no
[20540.007438] DMA free:628456kB min:11484kB low:14352kB high:17220kB active_anon:1324kB inactive_anon:292kB active_file:1624kB inactive_file:1236kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:2086900kB managed:2060924kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:4kB slab_unreclaimable:240kB kernel_stack:96kB pagetables:12kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:704kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:602084kB
[20540.007439] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 5837 5837 5837
[20540.007450] Normal free:33892kB min:33568kB low:41960kB high:50352kB active_anon:1428kB inactive_anon:2288kB active_file:236kB inactive_file:224kB unevictable:15520kB writepending:0kB present:6125568kB managed:5977956kB mlocked:16kB slab_reclaimable:41808kB slab_unreclaimable:73004kB kernel_stack:8048kB pagetables:9524kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:140kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
[20540.007451] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[20540.007458] DMA: 154*4kB (UC) 94*8kB (UMC) 71*16kB (MC) 37*32kB (UMC) 11*64kB (MC) 5*128kB (UMC) 4*256kB (C) 2*512kB (UC) 1*1024kB (C) 1*2048kB (C) 151*4096kB (UC) = 628648kB
[20540.007488] Normal: 279*4kB (UME) 167*8kB (UME) 153*16kB (UM) 121*32kB (UM) 68*64kB (UM) 21*128kB (M) 72*256kB (UM) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 34244kB
[20540.007513] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[20540.007514] 5320 total pagecache pages
[20540.007517] 571 pages in swap cache
[20540.007519] Swap cache stats: add 291106, delete 290668, find 14642/77423
[20540.007521] Free swap  = 131534904kB
[20540.007522] Total swap = 132019420kB
[20540.007524] 2053117 pages RAM
[20540.007525] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[20540.007527] 43397 pages reserved
[20540.007528] 188416 pages cma reserved
[20540.007529] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[20540.007555] [ 2204]     0  2204     4576        8      12       4      235             0 systemd-journal
[20540.007562] [ 2833]     0  2833     3909        9       7       3      406         -1000 systemd-udevd
[20540.007569] [ 4637] 62583  4637    20992        0      11       4      170             0 systemd-timesyn
[20540.007572] [ 4662]     0  4662     1920        2       8       3      798             0 haveged
[20540.007576] [ 4664]     0  4664     1602        0       7       3      131             0 rpcbind
[20540.007579] [ 4670]   102  4670     2612        0       9       4      173             0 systemd-resolve
[20540.007582] [ 4871]     0  4871    59300        0      18       5      319             0 accounts-daemon
[20540.007585] [ 4902]     0  4902    78223        0      20       4      428             0 ModemManager
[20540.007589] [ 4939]   114  4939     1541        0       7       3      146             0 avahi-daemon
[20540.007594] [ 4968]   109  4968    54993        8      12       3      863             0 rsyslogd
[20540.007599] [ 5005]   103  5005     2065        6       7       3      451          -900 dbus-daemon
[20540.007603] [ 5144]   114  5144     1491        0       7       3       84             0 avahi-daemon
[20540.007607] [ 5176]     0  5176     2418        0       8       4      244             0 wpa_supplicant
[20540.007611] [ 5177]     0  5177   101135        0      31       5     1004             0 NetworkManager
[20540.007615] [ 5191]     0  5191    97825        0      23       4     1180             0 udisksd
[20540.007620] [ 5207]     0  5207     1660        2       8       4       70             0 cron
[20540.007624] [ 5215]     0  5215     2638        0      10       4      208             0 systemd-logind
[20540.007628] [ 5367]     0  5367    59266        2      18       3      753             0 polkitd
[20540.007635] [ 5632]   111  5632    62056        0      23       5      517             0 whoopsie
[20540.007640] [ 5682]     0  5682   269941        0      58       7     5052             0 containerd
[20540.007643] [ 5715]   105  5715     2372        0       8       4      118             0 kerneloops
[20540.007647] [ 5755]     0  5755     1318        0       6       3       33             0 agetty
[20540.007651] [ 5763]   105  5763     2372        0       8       4      117             0 kerneloops
[20540.007654] [ 5792]     0  5792     2604        0      10       4      192         -1000 sshd
[20540.007657] [ 5828]     0  5828     1318        0       6       4       36             0 agetty
[20540.007662] [ 5829]     0  5829     1654        2       8       3       77             0 nvmemwarning.sh
[20540.007666] [ 5834]     0  5834     5375        0       7       3       68             0 nvs-service
[20540.007671] [ 5929]     0  5929    21197        0      29       3     1253             0 nvargus-daemon
[20540.007674] [ 6027]     0  6027    58903        0      18       5      376             0 gdm3
[20540.007679] [ 6240]     0  6240      786        0       4       3       37             0 nvphsd
[20540.007683] [ 6266]     0  6266     3045        0       6       3       88             0 nvphsd
[20540.007687] [ 6306]     0  6306    40899        0      17       3      376             0 gdm-session-wor
[20540.007691] [ 6362]  1000  6362     3344        2      10       4      525             0 systemd
[20540.007695] [ 6381]  1000  6381     4100        0      12       3      758             0 (sd-pam)
[20540.007699] [ 6403]  1000  6403    58867        0      16       4      279             0 gnome-keyring-d
[20540.007704] [ 6407]  1000  6407    39901        2      13       3      168             0 gdm-x-session
[20540.007707] [ 6409]  1000  6409  6350378      530      48       5     3650             0 Xorg
[20540.007711] [ 6415]  1000  6415     1903        5      10       3      363             0 dbus-daemon
[20540.007715] [ 6418]  1000  6418      568        1       5       3       34             0 run-systemd-ses
[20540.007719] [ 6495]  1000  6495    58783        0      16       3      783             0 gvfsd
[20540.007723] [ 6500]  1000  6500    94998        0      19       5      795             0 gvfsd-fuse
[20540.007728] [ 6505]  1000  6505    39575        0      12       3      159             0 gvfsd-metadata
[20540.007732] [ 6556]  1000  6556     1045        3       6       4       80             0 ssh-agent
[20540.007735] [ 6585]     0  6585     2089        2       7       3      317             0 dhclient
[20540.007739] [ 6669]  1000  6669     3206        0      10       4      173             0 systemctl
[20540.007742] [ 6680]  1000  6680   203418      208      59       4     2639             0 unity-settings-
[20540.007745] [ 6681]  1000  6681   135849        0      54       4     2882             0 indicator-keybo
[20540.007748] [ 6682]  1000  6682    72068        0      44       4     2588             0 bamfdaemon
[20540.007753] [ 6683]  1000  6683    77439        0      18       4      308             0 indicator-power
[20540.007757] [ 6684]  1000  6684    62377        0      22       4      900             0 indicator-appli
[20540.007762] [ 6685]  1000  6685   266628        0      60       5     1204             0 indicator-datet
[20540.007766] [ 6689]  1000  6689   114566        0      24       4      896             0 indicator-sessi
[20540.007769] [ 6690]  1000  6690    77338        0      18       3      266             0 indicator-bluet
[20540.007773] [ 6691]  1000  6691    78207        0      21       5      440             0 indicator-messa
[20540.007777] [ 6692]  1000  6692   228933        0      26       4      530             0 indicator-sound
[20540.007781] [ 6694]  1000  6694   119581        0      32       4      733             0 gnome-session-b
[20540.007785] [ 6727]     0  6727     1777        0       7       4      105             0 bluetoothd
[20540.007789] [ 6773]  1000  6773   302887        0      36       4     2074             0 pulseaudio
[20540.007793] [ 6777]   106  6777    38092        0       9       4      102             0 rtkit-daemon
[20540.007796] [ 6811]  1000  6811   250673        0      58       4     1217             0 evolution-sourc
[20540.007799] [ 6816]  1000  6816    77007        0      19       3      769             0 at-spi-bus-laun
[20540.007802] [ 6852]  1000  6852     1708        0       8       4      142             0 dbus-daemon
[20540.007805] [ 6861]  1000  6861    39831        0      13       4      735             0 at-spi2-registr
[20540.007808] [ 6868]  1000  6868    38763        0      11       3      210             0 dconf-service
[20540.007811] [ 6876]     0  6876    61833        0      18       3      329             0 upowerd
[20540.007814] [ 6926]  1000  6926   211543     1978      99       5     7600             0 compiz
[20540.007817] [ 6931]  1000  6931   129181        0      51       3     2071             0 goa-daemon
[20540.007820] [ 6939]  1000  6939   110468      287      38       4     1561             0 unity-panel-ser
[20540.007824] [ 6946]  1000  6946   144056        2      70       5    10038             0 evolution-calen
[20540.007827] [ 6961]  1000  6961    59960        0      19       4      361             0 goa-identity-se
[20540.007830] [ 6973]   116  6973    60995        0      21       4     1310             0 colord
[20540.007833] [ 7055]  1000  7055   240313        0      69       5     3818             0 nautilus-deskto
[20540.007836] [ 7056]  1000  7056    64823        0      29       4     1228             0 polkit-gnome-au
[20540.007840] [ 7057]  1000  7057   101651        0      33       4     1232             0 unity-fallback-
[20540.007843] [ 7118]  1000  7118   113478        0      43       5     1928             0 nm-applet
[20540.007846] [ 7198]  1000  7198    78150        0      21       3      807             0 gvfs-udisks2-vo
[20540.007850] [ 7254]  1000  7254    78059        0      19       4      405             0 gvfsd-trash
[20540.007853] [ 7267]  1000  7267    77594        0      18       3      413             0 ibus-daemon
[20540.007856] [ 7300]  1000  7300    57984        2      14       4      218             0 gvfs-goa-volume
[20540.007859] [ 7308]  1000  7308    58938        0      16       4      275             0 ibus-dconf
[20540.007862] [ 7332]  1000  7332    64878        0      30       4     1171             0 ibus-x11
[20540.007866] [ 7345]  1000  7345    58915        0      16       4      249             0 ibus-portal
[20540.007869] [ 7358]  1000  7358    40468        0      15       4      267             0 ibus-engine-sim
[20540.007872] [ 7359]  1000  7359    57953        0      14       3      225             0 gvfs-mtp-volume
[20540.007875] [ 7428]  1000  7428    78010        0      20       4      316             0 gvfs-afc-volume
[20540.007879] [ 7448]  1000  7448    58419        0      15       5      770             0 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
[20540.007882] [ 7512]  1000  7512   233505        0      75       4    10519             0 evolution-calen
[20540.007885] [ 7527]  1000  7527   130059        1      42       4      898             0 evolution-addre
[20540.007888] [ 7540]  1000  7540   203798        0      55       3     1566             0 evolution-addre
[20540.007891] [ 7667]  1000  7667   193125        0      43       5     1137             0 zeitgeist-datah
[20540.007894] [ 7676]  1000  7676    95412        0      19       3      316             0 zeitgeist-daemo
[20540.007898] [ 7682]  1000  7682    66618        0      19       4      833             0 zeitgeist-fts
[20540.007901] [ 7726]  1000  7726   102446        5      35       4     1271             0 update-notifier
[20540.007904] [ 7843]     0  7843    87227        0      35       5     1484             0 packagekitd
[20540.007907] [ 7928]     0  7928    59439        0      18       4      823             0 boltd
[20540.007910] [ 8259]  1000  8259   129503        0      50       3     1614             0 deja-dup-monito
[20540.007913] [ 8328]  1000  8328    91556        2      34       4     1530             0 unity-panel-ser
[20540.007917] [ 9281]     0  9281     3033        2      10       3      244             0 sshd
[20540.007920] [ 9362]  1000  9362     3106        0      10       3      264             0 sshd
[20540.007923] [ 9363]  1000  9363     2019       62       8       4      373             0 bash
[20540.007928] [ 9751]     0  9751     1190        0       6       4       20             0 sleep
[20540.007931] [10005]  1000 10005  4253560     2245      68       6    12484             0 testbed
[20540.007934] Out of memory: Kill process 10005 (testbed) score 0 or sacrifice child
[20540.015806] Killed process 10005 (testbed) total-vm:17014240kB, anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:8980kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[20540.059021] oom_reaper: reaped process 10005 (testbed), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:8948kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

According to the last two lines of this log, the program requires total of 17 GB memory, but the OS cannot offer sufficient space for this. I cannot understand why it was not available even though it has enough SWAP space. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks for your attention!

**PS.** If you know about [CUDA programming](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit), following information may help. (I am not sure)
Device profile:

```bash
$ /usr/local/cuda-10.2/samples/bin/aarch64/linux/release/deviceQuery -h
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/samples/bin/aarch64/linux/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "NVIDIA Tegra X2"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          10.2 / 10.2
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.2
  Total amount of global memory:                 7850 MBytes (8231813120 bytes)
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     256 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1300 MHz (1.30 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1300 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            Yes
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device supports Compute Preemption:            Yes
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            Yes
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 0 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.2, CUDA Runtime Version = 10.2, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

Running the deep learning program upon cuda-memcheck.

```bash
$ cuda-memcheck ./build/testbed --mode nerf --scene data/nerf/fox/
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Program hit cudaErrorDevicesUnavailable (error 46) due to "all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable" on CUDA API call to cudaMalloc.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libcuda.so.1 [0x2fdb04]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart.so.10.2 (cudaMalloc + 0x144) [0x3b68c]
=========
15:32:40 ERROR    Uncaught exception: Could not allocate memory: /home/nvidia/instant-ngp/dependencies/tiny-cuda-nn/include/tiny-cuda-nn/gpu_memory.h:124 cudaMalloc(&rawptr, n_bytes+DEBUG_GUARD_SIZE*2) failed with error all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

After further inspection, I conclude this is because of lack of memory in GPU as stated in the warning (GPUMemoryArena: Warning: GPU 0 does not support virtual memory. Falling back to regular allocations, which will be larger and can cause occasional stutter).

I found and ran the tegrastats program, which is served by tegra version cuda toolkit. It shows the deep learning program is killed around the gpu memory become full.

```
RAM 1832/7850MB (lfb 1176x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [2%@345,0%@345,0%@345,0%@345,2%@345,0%@345] EMC_FREQ 0%@665 GR3D_FREQ 0%@114 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@40C MCPU@40C PMIC@100C Tboard@35C GPU@39.5C BCPU@40C thermal@39.5C Tdiode@37.75C VDD_SYS_GPU 152/152 VDD_SYS_SOC 535/486 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/15 VDD_IN 1988/2020 VDD_SYS_CPU 229/240 VDD_SYS_DDR 211/214
RAM 1832/7850MB (lfb 1176x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [2%@345,0%@345,0%@345,0%@345,0%@345,0%@345] EMC_FREQ 0%@665 GR3D_FREQ 0%@114 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@40C MCPU@40C PMIC@100C Tboard@35C GPU@39.5C BCPU@40C thermal@39.5C Tdiode@37.75C VDD_SYS_GPU 152/152 VDD_SYS_SOC 459/485 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/15 VDD_IN 1950/2018 VDD_SYS_CPU 229/240 VDD_SYS_DDR 192/213
RAM 1844/7850MB (lfb 1167x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [21%@1986,0%@345,0%@345,1%@1991,1%@1984,1%@1981] EMC_FREQ 0%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 50%@114 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@40C MCPU@40C PMIC@100C Tboard@35C GPU@39.5C BCPU@40C thermal@39.3C Tdiode@37.75C VDD_SYS_GPU 152/152 VDD_SYS_SOC 611/488 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/14 VDD_IN 2866/2036 VDD_SYS_CPU 458/245 VDD_SYS_DDR 558/221
RAM 2268/7850MB (lfb 1107x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [86%@2029,0%@345,0%@345,87%@2030,85%@2027,81%@2030] EMC_FREQ 1%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 0%@114 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@42.5C MCPU@42.5C PMIC@100C Tboard@35C GPU@40C BCPU@42.5C thermal@40.1C Tdiode@38.25C VDD_SYS_GPU 152/152 VDD_SYS_SOC 916/497 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/14 VDD_IN 6563/2130 VDD_SYS_CPU 2900/300 VDD_SYS_DDR 1346/244
RAM 2286/7850MB (lfb 1102x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [18%@1113,0%@345,0%@345,10%@1113,12%@1113,7%@1113] EMC_FREQ 2%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 99%@1236 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@41C MCPU@41C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@41.5C BCPU@41C thermal@40.3C Tdiode@40.75C VDD_SYS_GPU 2365/197 VDD_SYS_SOC 916/505 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/14 VDD_IN 6258/2215 VDD_SYS_CPU 534/305 VDD_SYS_DDR 1307/266
RAM 2185/7850MB (lfb 1102x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [25%@652,0%@345,0%@345,11%@652,14%@653,13%@653] EMC_FREQ 3%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 97%@1300 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@41C MCPU@41C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@43C BCPU@41C thermal@41.8C Tdiode@41.5C VDD_SYS_GPU 3661/266 VDD_SYS_SOC 991/515 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/13 VDD_IN 7476/2320 VDD_SYS_CPU 305/305 VDD_SYS_DDR 1365/288
RAM 3246/7850MB (lfb 1017x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [3%@345,0%@345,0%@345,53%@345,0%@345,0%@345] EMC_FREQ 8%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 99%@1300 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@41.5C MCPU@41.5C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@42.5C BCPU@41.5C thermal@41.3C Tdiode@41.25C VDD_SYS_GPU 2973/319 VDD_SYS_SOC 1144/527 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/13 VDD_IN 8006/2431 VDD_SYS_CPU 457/308 VDD_SYS_DDR 2000/321
RAM 3246/7850MB (lfb 1017x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [3%@345,0%@345,0%@345,2%@345,0%@345,0%@345] EMC_FREQ 18%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 99%@1300 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@41.5C MCPU@41.5C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@42.5C BCPU@41.5C thermal@42C Tdiode@41.25C VDD_SYS_GPU 3047/371 VDD_SYS_SOC 1372/543 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/13 VDD_IN 9828/2574 VDD_SYS_CPU 304/308 VDD_SYS_DDR 3115/375
RAM 5600/7850MB (lfb 448x4MB) SWAP 392/128925MB (cached 23MB) CPU [1%@2021,0%@345,0%@345,7%@2026,83%@2023,0%@2024] EMC_FREQ 14%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 0%@1300 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@42C MCPU@42C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@41.5C BCPU@42C thermal@41.9C Tdiode@39.5C VDD_SYS_GPU 839/380 VDD_SYS_SOC 1068/553 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/13 VDD_IN 5876/2636 VDD_SYS_CPU 839/318 VDD_SYS_DDR 1807/402
RAM 6739/7850MB (lfb 182x4MB) SWAP 427/128925MB (cached 3MB) CPU [51%@2021,0%@345,0%@345,95%@2022,73%@2022,8%@2022] EMC_FREQ 4%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 0%@1300 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@43C MCPU@43C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@41C BCPU@43C thermal@42.2C Tdiode@39.5C VDD_SYS_GPU 228/377 VDD_SYS_SOC 992/561 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/12 VDD_IN 6449/2706 VDD_SYS_CPU 2366/356 VDD_SYS_DDR 1346/419
RAM 1762/7850MB (lfb 1122x4MB) SWAP 424/128925MB (cached 4MB) CPU [36%@499,0%@345,0%@345,36%@498,4%@499,16%@499] EMC_FREQ 3%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 0%@1300 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@41.5C MCPU@41.5C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@40.5C BCPU@41.5C thermal@41.3C Tdiode@39.5C VDD_SYS_GPU 229/375 VDD_SYS_SOC 916/568 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/12 VDD_IN 4239/2734 VDD_SYS_CPU 687/362 VDD_SYS_DDR 1230/434
RAM 1762/7850MB (lfb 1122x4MB) SWAP 424/128925MB (cached 4MB) CPU [3%@345,0%@345,0%@345,1%@345,0%@345,1%@345] EMC_FREQ 1%@1866 GR3D_FREQ 0%@1300 VIC_FREQ 0%@115 APE 150 MTS fg 0% bg 0% PLL@41.5C MCPU@41.5C PMIC@100C Tboard@36C GPU@40.5C BCPU@41.5C thermal@41.1C Tdiode@39.25C VDD_SYS_GPU 229/372 VDD_SYS_SOC 917/574 VDD_4V0_WIFI 0/12 VDD_IN 3553/2749 VDD_SYS_CPU 305/361 VDD_SYS_DDR 1134/447
```

I need to modify the program to load less data on the gpu memory.

Comment: This isn’t really correct. The OOM killer  is a linux kernel initiated process when the system is out of memory. Where Tegra systems are unique is that the host CPU and GPU share memory, there is no separate GPU memory. So this isn’t you running out of GPU memory, it is you running out of system memory.

Comment: @talonmies, thanks for your comment. That's why OOM kills the program because the memory OOM is watching is used GPU as well as CPU.